# Why is compiler showing error while importing javafx.scene.control.Label?

Tags: java, javafx, label

I am learning javafx and I am trying to create label. But while importing `javafx.scene.control.Label`, I am getting error : `The import javafx.scene.control.Label conflicts with a type defined in the same file`

The whole code is :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class Label extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("This is a label");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        root.getChildren().add(label);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
        
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: compare the name of your app with the name in the error message ...

Answer (score 0):

Type names in the scope of a class need to be unique. You define a new class called `Label` while importing another class that is also called `Label`. So if you write `Label` in your code, the compiler does not know which class to use.

You can either rename your class (so it does not conflict) or not import the other class. Note that even without importing,

```
javafx.scene.control.Label label = new javafx.scene.control.Label();
```

will work, but it's quite ugly.

EDIT: As your class extends `Application` you probably want to rename it to somithing like `LabelApp` or whatever the app does

Answer (score 0):

This is because Main thread is looking for predefined `Label`class argument. But here, it got start method() with user defined `Label` class. Whenever Main thread will see a class name, it tries to search that class scope by scope. First it will see in your program, then in your package.If not found, then JVM follows delegation hierarchy principle to load that class.Hence you will get run-time error.

To run above program, we can also provide full path of Label class, i.e.
`javafx.scene.control.Label label = new javafx.scene.control.Label("This is a label");` .

conclusion- please change your class name,you can use the above solution but it gets messy .